# How can apply sorting on django rest serializer custom fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have serializer for user detail and I want to apply sorting on serializer custom fields.

```
class ABCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
      
      def get_status(self, obj):
          if obj.status == 'Draft':
               return 'Draft'
          elif obj.status == 'Inactive':
               return 'Inactive'
          else:
            if obj.publish_start_date and obj.publish_start_date > timezone.now():
                return "Upcoming"
            elif obj.publish_end_date and obj.publish_end_date < timezone.now():
                return "Expired"
            return 'Active'
```

Comment: Sort needs to happen in database level, so you need to write a query. Most likely you need to write a query that combines annotation, conditional expressions and sort.

Answer (score 0):

Sort needs to happen in database level, so you need to write a query. Most likely you need to do something like this:

Write a query that combines annotation, conditional expressions and sort.
Something like, `ABC.objects.annotate(status='your case query')).sort_by('status').`  Make output of 'your case query' as an integer so that sorting becomes possible. And pass that queryset to the serializer. Your `get_status` function in serializer  need to only need code `return obj.status`; your logic is already in the query.